# Register Firebase service worker with existing workbox worker

Tags: angular, firebase, vue.js, service-worker, workbox

I'm using Google's [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) for some offline features and caching in my angular 9, app. For push messages, we're using Google's [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com).

Since updating the web app to Vue.js I receive an error when accessing the website:

> Uncaught FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://my-domain.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('https://my-domain.com/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

Yes, there is no *firebase-messaging-sw.js* in the root directory.
Everything should be handled by Workbox.

I followed the documentation to use an existing service worker for registration by the function `useServiceWorker()`, but this causes the mentioned error.

```js
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/messaging';
import { Workbox } from 'workbox-window';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

...

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
  const scope = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname.split('/').slice(0, 3).join('/');
  const wb = new Workbox('/my-worker.js', { scope: scope });

  wb.register().then(reg => {
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
    }
    if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
      firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(reg);
    }
    reg.update();
  }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Do I need a *firebase-messaging-sw.js*?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this issue out? I am running into the same issue.